# How to implement a local logging system?

Tags: java, android, logging

I'm making an app for android that requires me to log the results and input parameters. My problem is that I don't know how to make efficient software to accomplish this. Unfortunately I can't use a database, because the device doesn't have access to internet, so I have to save my files locally. There is about 10 parameters per log, and it should be fast to search by each and one of them. Also I want avoid files that are too big.

This is the first time I'm coding something like this as a college hobbyist, so I don't have much experience in this field. That's why i was hoping i could get some pointers on how to implement it, or some classes that already handle this kind of task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use a database! Android supplies the ability to create locally-stored SQLite databases just for this very purpose.

Example taken from [Storage Options | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db):

```
public class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME = "dictionary";
    private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                KEY_WORD + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_DEFINITION + " TEXT);";

    DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE);
    }
}
```